# MySQL import column into table that matches key

Tags: mysql

I've got 2 MySQL tables that I want to merge into one. I've been searching and I couldn't found the way of doing this specific merge:

I want to import a column from table B (key, column) to a new column of table A(key, column1,column2...). This is easy. But only the values of table B that its key is equal to a key of A, and I want it to be in that row.

For example: if I had this 2 tables:

```
TABLE1           TABLE 2
ID NAME          ID TEAM
1  "name1"       1  "bt"
                 2  "bt2"
```

I want the result to be:

```
TABLE1           
ID NAME     TEAM    
1  "name1"  "bt"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use `update` with `join`:

```
update table1 t1 join
       table2 t2
       on t1.id = t2.id
    set t1.team = t2.team;
```

However, there really is no reason to do this.  You seem to be starting with a normalized data structure, and this is usually a good thing.  You can just join in the value wherever you need it, perhaps by creating a view (if you really want).